# PHP preg_replace. Replace AB with CD only if it is not preceded or terminated by "-"

Tags: php, regex, preg-replace

I have a problem with `preg_match()`. I have a string with special characters that tell me that part of the string needs to be replaced, and what not. But I can't find the pattern able to do it. I hope you will be able to help me.

An example:

"AB-" or "-AB" or "AB" => Replace with CD

"-AB-" => Do not replace with CD

```
$str = 'AB-AB-ABAB-AB--AB-AB'; //Actual string
$ptr = '  ????  ';
$rem = 'CD';

echo preg_replace($ptr, $rem, $str); // It should be "CD-AB-CDCD-AB--AB-CD"
```

I've been trying with `/(?!\-)AB(?!\-)/` and some stuff like this but got only partial results...

Thx for the help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use lookahead and lookbehind assertions:

```
$repl = preg_replace('/((?<!-)AB|AB(?!-))/', 'CD', 'AB-AB-ABAB-AB--AB-AB');
//=> CD-AB-CDCD-AB--AB-CD
```

Comment: FWIW the brackets surrounding the whole expression are not needed in this case.